# antlr4 matching of choice expression

Tags: parsing, antlr4, grun

Im writing chrome [DEPS file](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/DEPS) parser. How to match one of either following grammar rule defintion of rightexpr. My grammar is like
the following one:

```
grammar Depsgrammar;

prog:   expr+ EOF;

expr:   varline
   ;
   
varline:  
   ID EQ  rightexpr  
    ;

rightexpr :  
    basicvalue | bentukonejsonval| bentuktwojsonval  
   ;
   
bentukonejsonval :
   '[' string?  (COMMA string )* COMMA? ']'
    ;
   
bentuktwojsonval :
    '{' singledictexpr?  (COMMA singledictexpr )* COMMA? '}'
   ;
   
singledictexpr :
    string ':' basicvalue
   ;
   
basicvalue :
 True
| False
| string
| NUM
| varfunc
;


varfunc :
 Var '(' string ')'
 ;

string :
 SIMPLESTRINGEXPRDOUBLEQUOTE
| SIMPLESTRINGEXPRSINGLEQUOTE
;

Var : 'Var' ;
COMMA : ',' ;
NUM : [0-9]+;
ID : [a-zA-Z0-9_]+;
True : [tT] [Rr] [Uu] [Ee];
False: [Ff] [Aa] [Ll] [Ss] [Ee];

fragment SIMPLESTRINGEXPRDOUBLEQUOTEBASE :   ~ ( '\n' | '\r' | '"' )*  ;
SIMPLESTRINGEXPRDOUBLEQUOTE: '"' SIMPLESTRINGEXPRDOUBLEQUOTEBASE '"' ;
fragment SIMPLESTRINGEXPRSINGLEQUOTEBASE :   ~ ( '\n' | '\r' | '\'' )* ;
SIMPLESTRINGEXPRSINGLEQUOTE : '\'' SIMPLESTRINGEXPRSINGLEQUOTEBASE '\'' ;
EQ : '=';
COMMENT:
  '#' ~ ( '\n' | '\r' )* '\n' -> skip ;

WS : [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip ;
```

I want user could enter this input

```
#adas21 #FS;SFD33
_as= Var('das') # somelongth comment
_as_0= FALSE # somelongth comment
_as_0= 'as!' # somelongth comment
gclient_gn_args = [

#ad as!~;
'checkout_libaom',
'checkout_nacl',
'"{cros_board}" == "amd64-generic"',
'checkout_oculus_sdk',
 ]


 vars = {
 'checkout_libaom':1,
 'checkout_nacl': "SS",
 'checkout_oculus_sdk': FalSe,
 'checkout_oculus_sdk':'',
  }

 s=[
 ]
```

whenever I enter simple syntax in grun

```
sa=true
```

always give me line 1:3 mismatched input 'true' expecting blah..(rightexpr def). I'm missing in understanding of basic antlr4 choice matching decision. Could you please teach me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have an error where the list of expected tokens seemingly includes the unexpected token, it is a good idea to list the generated tokens. You can do that by passing the `-tokens` option to `grun`. If you do this for your input, you'll see that `true` is interpreted as an `ID` token, not a `True` token.

The reason for that is that when multiple lexer rules would match on the current input and produce a match of the same size, the one that's defined earlier in the grammar is chosen. So because `ID` is defined before `True`, it takes precedence. Generally all keywords should be defined before the `ID` rule to prevent exactly this issue.

In other words, moving the `True` and `False` rules before `ID` will solve your issue.

Comment: thanks, how stupid I am.. just a little change in the order of declarations of the lexer changes is very influential .. leason learned today